# How to delaying specific response from fake backend in Sinon JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

In my App I use - Backbone framework. Karma, Jasmine, SinonJS - for testing.

I have simple Backbone view, like this:

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ‘#app’,
    initialize: function () {
        var collection1 = new Collection1();// creates collection which can receive data from backend
        var collection2 = new Collection2(); // another one

        collection1.fetch().done(function() { // backbone sends the request for data to backend
            //render data1 which received from backend and append to el
        });
        collection2.fetch().done(function() {
            //render data2 which received from backend and append to el
        });
    }
});
```

Two Collections send different requests (different urls).

I need to test this code, and I need make situation when collection2 will return data from backend after collection1. This situation needs to be guaranteed. It’s a main idea of this test.

I know how to delay all request to fake backend, but I don’t understand how to delay one of them.

I use async test from this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joewilson/b5vft6xy/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=b5vft6xy)

My code for test:

```
define(function(require) {

    //get all dependencies

    function testAsync(delayTime) { // make delay
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve();
        }, delayTime);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
    describe('test ', function() {
        var view = null,
            server = null;

        beforeEach(function(done) {
            server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); // fake sinon server
            server.autoRespond = true;          // enable autoanswer

        testAsync(3000)                     // delay 3 sec
        .done(function(done) {
                server.respondWith('GET', urlsForRequest.collection1, [
                    200,
                    {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                    mockData1]);
                server.respondWith('GET', urlsForRequest.collection2, [
                    200,
                    {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                    mockData2]);
                done(); // all is good go to it section, it's a jasmine func
            });

            view = new View(); // create Backbone View

        });

        afterEach(function() {
            server.restore();
        });

        it('can be instantiated', function() {
            // in this section need to use expect
        });

    });
});
```

This test is delaying all responses, but I need delaying only for one.

How can I change this code, for implement test correct?

PS. For T.J.
I tried to use this code, result the same

```
server.respondWith('GET', urlsForRequest.collection2, function(fakeRequest) {
    fakeRequest.autoRespond = true;
    fakeRequest.autoRespondAfter = 3000;
    fakeRequest.respond(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, mockData2);
    done();
});
```

Comment: I said in my answer to **NOT** use `autoRespond` or `autoRespondAfter` but you are using it. They are properties of server but you are setting them on the request, I don't know why. I don't understand what the `done();` is for in the updated code. finally if all else fails, I mentioned you can make the requests synchronous with`async` option. But you are setting it to `true` and keeping it asynchronous.  You are doing a combination of things and doing it wrong, please read the answer carefully and do things 1 by 1, remove the unnecessary code and properties

Comment: I used to all methods. With, without autoRespond autoRespondAfter. I used to setTimeout like you say - it's not work. When I run without setTimeout. Fake server get async answer, but first collection1.fetch (after 10ms) and next to collection2.fetch (after 10ms). 10ms - it's default delay for async response. If I run second responseWith in setTimeout func, I receive only response from first, and data from second response not preseted in 'it' section. I don't find in documentation any words how can I implement for one request default delay (10 ms), for another one 3000 ms

Comment: The problem is probably you thinking of fake server similar to real server, trying to execute the test as it happens in real world. It is a fakeserver and it only responds to matching requests when you tell it to respond. So you can send a request, tell the server to respond, send another request, tell the server to respond. So you get the request responses in the order you wish, it's as simple as that. You're probably using the same fakeserver instance that is being used for other tests, which is set to autorespond to requests and things like that.

Comment: Create a small test outside your application and test what I mentioned above.

Comment: Yep, I thought about this way. But, in sinonJs, If I understand correct. Exists two way for sending responses.First -config  autoRespond = true. When you send request, fakeServer send async respond after 10 ms by default. Second, when you manually send respond using server.respond() method. This method send responses for all requests in queue. I don't know how manually respond for specific request. :(

Comment: If you do `server.respond()` it responds to all requests. *"I don't know how manually respond for specific request"* - `server.respondWith(url, response);` is the way to respond to only requests matching url.... That means the other request will still keep waiting until you decide. You already have it in your code. You probably only need to try this in a small demo isolated from your project and you'll figure it out...

Comment: `server.respondWith` only registrate url and all options (code, method, body) for request at this url. Responses send from fakeServes to App automatically or manually according to config.

Comment: The documentation states: "`server.respondWith(url, response);`

**Responds to all requests to given URL, e.g. /posts/1."**. If it is not doing that (responding to existing requests in queue, I don't know why it's not) when a response is added,  you can add these responses upfront, send first request, `server.respond()`, send second request, `server.respond()`. You can control the order of responses like this

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't set `autoRespond = true` in this kind of tests at all. From documentation of `autoRespond` : "Note that this feature is intended to help during mockup development, and is not suitable for use in tests"

Comment: **Responds to all requests to given URL, e.g. /posts/1."** yes all is right in this section. You register respondWith (in what code, and method need to answer) and when your app call '/posts/1' this response send it. My block has two requests. All requests are doing sync one after another and wait async responses. So I can't send server.respond() after each. I tend to sync that I can't realise my case.

Comment: @TJ I found the solution. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so my solution.

First, I disabled all `autoRespond` option and removed `server.respond()` for manually respond.

Next after debugging I found in fake server option - `queue`. This queue has array with all fake requests to fake server, if you have a lot of requests. Exists special options (`firstRequest`, `secondRequest`, `thirdRequest` and `lastRequest`). Each fakeRequest has method `respond(code, contentType-Object, body)`, and you can use it for send response for specific request by manually.

So my code of test after all changes implemented like this:

```
define(function(require) {

    //get all dependencies

    describe('test ', function() {
        var view = null,
            server = null;

        beforeAll(function(done) {              // need to save view beetwen requests, change to beforeAll
            server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); // fake sinon server
            view = new View();                  // create Backbone View
            done();                             // run this jasmine-method to say jasmine - "All is good, run immediately tests in it-sections"

        });

        afterAll(function() {
            server.restore();
            view = null;
        });

        it('run response for second request by firstly', function() {
            server.secondRequest.respond(200,
                {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                mockData2);
            // in this section need to use expect and check state of view
        });
        it('run response for first request by secondly', function() {
            server.firstRequest.respond(200,
                {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                mockData1);
            // in this section need to use expect and check state of view
        });

    });
});
```

My devDep:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.4",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "sinon": "^2.3.6"
  }
```

Comment: The `done()` in my knowledge is for handling asynchronous actions, for example in `beforeAll()` if you need to wait for a request or something you call `done() ` after it is complete, in this example since you don't have anything like that `done()` is unnecessary. Btw congrats for finding a solution

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set `server.autoRespond = true;` in this case. Also, you don't need the `testAsync` function because sinon has built in option for it, if it was necessary: `server.autoRespondAfter`.

Just respond to the request you want to succeed first,

```
server.respondWith('GET', urlsForRequest.collection1, [
                200,
                {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                mockData1]);
```

And then respond to the second request, maybe wrap it in a timeout to make sure it's added to the queue after the previous one:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 server.respondWith('GET', urlsForRequest.collection2, [
                200,
                {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                mockData2]);
}, 0);
```

If that doesn't work for some reason finally you have:

> `boolean request.async`
>
> Whether or not the request is asynchronous.

You can make them synchronous for the purpose of the test to make sure one finish after another.

Comment: I tried to use setTimeout, but in IT-section I don’t have data from collection2.
It’s not work. Next I tried to use autorespondAfter in fakeRequest. Have the same result. Add code to my main message. FakeRequest has async = true option